# Not all mails being received by recipients when sent via PHP using Amazon SES

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, newsletter, amazon-ses

I wrote simple PHP (codeigniter) script to send newsletter with Amazon SES. I have ~8000 emails in MySQL table and script which pulls all rows (email addresses), splits it in smaller packages (because of SES limits) and send email via SMTP. I'm using `sleep()*` and a cronjob which runs every minute. I know that isn’t the best solution but as a concept it works fine.

To allow sending mails with `bcc`, I have to make sure there is at last one recipient in `to` field or Amazon SES will not send it. So, my address (`news@baulink.rs`) is always in `to` and the other addresses are in `bcc`. Every iteration puts 8 different addresses in `bcc` (BTW, is there any better solution for this?). I also have a simple log file which writes every address operated by my application.

As I see, some recipients don’t get the newsletter. Amazon SES returns bounced emails and that works fine, but some addresses doesn't get it at all and there is no any feedback from Amazon SES. These addresses are in my log, which means they are processed by PHP script. Then I just delete that address and insert again in MySQL table and - it works! Some e-mails are parsed from CSV file, some of were inserted manually. I really don't know and can't check with all recipients if they got the newsletter. Do you have any idea what could cause this strange behavior?

I can't figure out what is the problem.

I'm using CodeIgniter and PHPMailer.

```
 public function cronSendMail(){
    $newsletter = $this->baumodel->getNewsletter();

    if(is_array($newsletter)){
        echo "No job for me!";    
        return;
    }elseif(is_object($newsletter)){ //means there is a newsletter ready for sending                        
        $limit = 104;
        $newsOfset = $newsletter->news_slanje_ofset;                        
        $noviOfset = $newsOfset+$limit;

        $adrese = $this->baumodel->getAdresar($limit, $newsOfset); 
        $brojAdresa = count($this->baumodel->getSveAdrese()); //number of recipients in whole MySQL table

        if($brojAdresa < $newsOfset){ 
            echo "Adrese: ".$brojAdresa;
            echo " Ofset: " .$newsOfset;
            die('Job is finished! ');
        }

        $this->baumodel->setNewsletterOfset($newsletter->news_id, $noviOfset);                      
        $emailArray = array();

        foreach($adrese as $adr){
            array_push($emailArray, trim($adr['adr_email']));
        }

        $newsletterContent = $newsletter->news_sadrzaj;                                                                                     
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->clear();                

        $maliNiz = array();
        for($i=0; $i<13; $i++){
            //13 times with 2 seconds sleep is ~30-35 seconds of execution time.
            //CronJob runs every minute
            $j=0;
            $maliNiz[$j] = array_pop($emailArray);
            $j++;
            $maliNiz[$j] = array_pop($emailArray);
            $j++;
            $maliNiz[$j] = array_pop($emailArray);
            $j++;
            $maliNiz[$j] = array_pop($emailArray);
            $j++;                           
            $maliNiz[$j] = array_pop($emailArray);
            $j++;
            $maliNiz[$j] = array_pop($emailArray);
            $j++;
            $maliNiz[$j] = array_pop($emailArray);
            $j++;
            $maliNiz[$j] = array_pop($emailArray);
            $j++;                           

            $this->email->to('news@baulink.rs');
            $this->email->bcc($maliNiz); //This is my BCC array of 8 addresses
            $this->email->from('office@baulink.rs', 'Baulink Portal');
            $this->email->subject('Gradjevinski portal Baulink - Novo na portalu');
            $this->email->message($newsletterContent);
            $this->email->send();
            //echo $this->email->print_debugger();

            sleep(2);               

            //log file start
            $filepath = APPPATH . 'logs/mail-log-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.php';
            $handle = fopen($filepath, "a+");                                                       
            $currentDateTime = date('d.M.Y H:i:s');
            foreach($maliNiz as $emailAdresa){
                    $infoLog = $emailAdresa . " // ".$currentDateTime . " \n";
                    fwrite($handle, $infoLog);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            //log file end
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not even in SPAM. There are for example some Gmail accounts which works great and messages are delivered in Inbox, but in some other cases it doesn't work at all. Similar is with @hotmail and domain-based (business) e-mail addresses. Really weird...

Comment: I will try to log the answers from SMTP, that will give me more data to analyse. It's probably something on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per amazon docs, this could be the issue.

> Important When you send an email to multiple recipients (recipients
>   are "To", "CC", and "BCC" addresses) and the call to Amazon SES fails,
>   the entire email is rejected and none of the recipients will receive
>   the intended email. We therefore recommend that you send an email to
>   one recipient at a time.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email.html

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but forgot about it. I will have to rewrite my script. RTFM :)

Comment: If you use the Amazon PHP SDK, you can connect to the API directly rather then through smtp, and that will allow you to send batches of emails. The only downside is if you want to switch mail provider you are up for a re-write.

Comment: Is it faster if I use the Amazon PHP SDK? Now it takes about 3 seconds for each request and if I send to only one recipient per request, it's very slow.

Comment: And I think that SES will also reject entire email if the call to server fails, doesn't metter if it's called by SMTP or by the regular API.

Comment: On further reading it does look like the same problem will occur with the api. I looked at SES docs when if first came out but haven't looked since. I ended up using mandrill.

Comment: This is not true. My "BCC" is receiving but my "To" is not.